# Not being able to create category

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I tried to create a function that creates a category upon certain conditions.

It should create a category if there are no categories called "Server Information"

Code:

```
public class EventListener extends ListenerAdapter {

    //Checks if target category exists, if it is - do nothing, and if it does not - create one
    String categoryInfoName = "Server Information";
    
    @Override
    public void onGenericGuild(GenericGuildEvent event) {
        try {
            if (!event.getGuild().getCategories().stream().anyMatch(category -> category.getName().equals(categoryInfoName))) {
                event.getGuild().createCategory(categoryInfoName);
            }
        }

        catch (InsufficientPermissionException permissionException)
        {
            permissionException.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

No matter what I change in Discord's server settings it still gives me these errors:

```
net.dv8tion.jda.api.exceptions.InsufficientPermissionException: Cannot perform action due to a lack of Permission. Missing permission: MANAGE_CHANNEL
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.entities.GuildImpl.checkPermission(GuildImpl.java:1898)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.entities.GuildImpl.checkCanCreateChannel(GuildImpl.java:1934)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.entities.GuildImpl.createChannel(GuildImpl.java:1729)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.entities.GuildImpl.createCategory(GuildImpl.java:1724)
    at me.izmike.jdabot.listeners.EventListener.onGenericGuild(EventListener.java:22)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter.onEvent(ListenerAdapter.java:424)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.InterfacedEventManager.handle(InterfacedEventManager.java:96)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.hooks.EventManagerProxy.handleInternally(EventManagerProxy.java:88)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.hooks.EventManagerProxy.handle(EventManagerProxy.java:70)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.JDAImpl.handleEvent(JDAImpl.java:171)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.GuildSetupNode.completeSetup(GuildSetupNode.java:376)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.GuildSetupNode.handleMemberChunk(GuildSetupNode.java:260)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Give your bot permissions to manage channels in its roles. Make sure you are giving the role to the bot and that you are modifying the correct bot that corresponds to your code.

Comment: I already did. It won't work though. Is there something else I can try to do?